# How to get Instagram Integration authorization_code?

Tags: curl, instagram, integration

Kindly help, how to get authorization_code?

```
curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI' \
-F 'code=CODE'
```

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid grant_type"}

It is quite confusing. I need USER_ID.

Someone say, its authorization_code is the param. But I did not understand it. What is param here.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is a very late reply but I hope it will help others:

PHP Code:

Step-1: Get code using client_id and redirect domain where you will get the code in response. It will just redirect to your redirect_uri domain with the query string of code parameter.

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http_domain_dot_com&response_type=code
```

Step-2: Make a POST request to get access_token using client_id, client_secret and the code you received with your redirect_uri from Step-1.

I am using PHP code here for example:

```
$post = ['client_id'=> "5b623cdffe6359694fcca2f772",
    'client_secret'=> "0fafe0a956dd1bfc81c74cdd9c",
    'grant_type'=> "authorization_code",
    'redirect_uri'=> "your domain using http",
    'code'=> "58f6905548f45c35623f5cd85"];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($response);

var_dump($result);
```

You will get the access_token in response. Now you can access the feed using https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=8626207.5b6cd.a45ae4d343329ed05429567966d9

Now you can print the feed data by reading json response:

```
$userId = 'self';
$accessToken = '860000207.5b0000d.a4500003e004033200500950000600';
$imageNumber = '6';
$imageResolution = 'thumbnail'; // thumbnail, low_resolution, standard_resolution

$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $userId . '/media/recent/?access_token=' . $accessToken.'&count='.$imageNumber;
$args = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 2500,)));
$instagramFeedsData = file_get_contents($url, false, $args);
$instagramFeeds = json_decode($instagramFeedsData);

$instangramData = $instagramFeeds->data;
foreach ($instangramData as $instagramFeed) {
$instagramImage = $instagramFeed->images->$imageResolution->url;
$caption_text = 'Instagram';
if (is_object($instagramFeed->caption)) {
    $caption_text = $instagramFeed->caption->text;
}
?>
<div class="instangram-feed">
    <a href ="<?php echo $instagramFeed->link; ?>" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo $instagramImage; ?>" title="<?php echo $caption_text; ?>" alt="<?php echo $caption_text; ?>"/>
    </a>               
</div>
<?php } ?>
```